# OnsenUI + Android4.0〜4.3でチェックボックスのアニメーションが遅い

Tags: onsen-ui

ons-page内に以下のようなチェックボックスを配置してクリックした場合、iOSでは即時チェックマークが表示されますが、Androidではワンテンポ遅れて表示されます。
FastClickが入ってないCheckboxをクリックするイメージが近いかと思います。

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div class="checkbox__checkmark"></div>
    test
</label>
```

動作確認はテンプレートコードをダウンロード（http://ja.onsen.io/project-templates/gen/onsenui-tab-bar.zip）し、部分的に改修したものをデバッグビルドでapk化し実機およびエミュレータへインストールして行っています。
実機はAndroid4.1(GalaxyS3)と4.3(GalaxyNote3)と4.4(GalaxyS4)と5.1(Nexus5)で確認しました。
エミュレータはGenymotionで4.0から5.1までをテストしてます。

実機は4.4からiPhoneと大差ないチェック動作ですが、4.3や4.1ではワンテンポ遅れて表示されます。
複数個のチェックボックスをつけるようなシーンでは人間のほうが動作が早くなります。

エミュレータはマシン性能によるところもあるのでなんとも言えない部分もあるのですが、5.1まで含めて遅い感じもします。
ただし5.0以上で分離されているWebViewの更新は行ってない状態（Genymotion仮想マシン素の状態）です。

実機、エミュレータともにCrosswalk(1.3.0/14.43.343.23)を組み込んだ場合、全て即時表示されるようになります。
ですのでタイトルとしてはAndroidに搭載されているWebViewというほうが適切かもしれません。

動作が遅くなってしまうWebViewを搭載している端末では、実質仕様（制限）となってしまうのでしょうか。

Comment: 実機で確認された際、4.4は正常で4.1のみ遅かったということでしょうか？